# how will gcc react to -O2 and -O0 in the same command?

Tags: gcc

Anyone has any ideas which will take preference if -O2 and -O0 is specified in the command line for gcc? I have some legacy code that gets configuration from multiple places....

Comment: It will taunt you mercilessly :-)

Comment: :P I've tried it now. However I didn't thought that the ordering would be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
λ > g++ outer.cxx -O2 -Os -o outer
λ > sha1sum outer                 
c3f62ab60393266388a8a7fb2d204d4b1f9dc145  outer
λ > g++ outer.cxx -Os -O2 -o outer
λ > sha1sum outer
355052e82d0146a185c8a1b845c7ed6db18087f1  outer
λ > g++ outer.cxx -O2 -o outer
λ > sha1sum outer
355052e82d0146a185c8a1b845c7ed6db18087f1  outer
λ > g++ outer.cxx -Os -o outer
λ > sha1sum outer
c3f62ab60393266388a8a7fb2d204d4b1f9dc145  outer
```

The last specified optimization flag wins.

Answer (score 4):

Last flag wins.  That lets them be overridden in a makefile.